NestJS tests (Jest) never terminated while using mongoose
I am using Mongoose to connect to MongoDB. While testing my code with Jest, the tests passed but never terminated.
In my mongoDB.service.ts I have:
  private connections: Map<number, Connection> = new Map();
  private connection: Connection;

Because I want to connect multiple dbs.
I use the connection to set the db connection and add it to the connections map
this.connection.useDb(dbName);

I implemented OnApplicationShutdown:
async onApplicationShutdown(): Promise<void> {
    for (const [orgId, connection] of this.connections) {
      await connection
        .close()
        .then(() => {
          console.log(`Connection for organization ID ${orgId} closed.`);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.error(`Failed to close connection for organization ID ${orgId}: ${e}`);
        });
    }
    this.connections.clear();
    await this.connection
      .close()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Secondary MongoDB connection closed.");
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(`Failed to close secondary MongoDB connection: ${e}`);
      });
    await mongoose.connection
      .close()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Primary MongoDB connection closed.");
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(`Failed to close primary MongoDB connection: ${e}`);
      });
  }

In my tests I have afterAll():
  afterAll(async () => {
    await module.close();
  }, 60000);

I debugged it, and it seems that the connections are closed. However, the tests never terminated.
I know it has been asked before MongoDB connections do not close in test scenarios, but never answered.
How to solve it?

so apparently, the problem is in Mongoose and not in its use of it.

We strongly recommend using a different testing framework, like Mocha.


Absolutely do not use timer mocks when testing Mongoose apps. This is especially important if you're using Jest >=25, which stubs out process.nextTick().

For more information: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/jest.html
